# Getting the node link in views-view-fields.html.twig

Tags: views, theming, 8, blocks

I've created a block display view to list recent posts on a page. Which variable can I use inside the `views-view-fields.html.twig` template file in order to retrieve the link to the post?

```
<div class="thumbnails thumbnail-style thumbnail-kenburn">
  <div class="thumbnail-img">
    <div class="overflow-hidden">
        {{ fields.field_image.content }}
    </div>
    <a class="btn-more hover-effect" href="{{ ??? }}">read more +</a>
  </div>
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>{{ fields.title.content }}</h3>
    {{ fields.body.content }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "Path" field and include it in the view. It should be something like: {field.path.content} You can always format it :D